# The Formula disappears partially when converting from odt to pdf

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, odt

I have this in odt:
[image]

When exporting as pdf from libre writer, I end up with:

[image]

As you can see, the parts that I put them using insert -> formula, disappears partially. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this happens when (the computer's memory is less<sup>*</sup> and) the document has large number of formulas [1].

A workaround would be to increase the cache size of OLE objects, i.e. go to **Tools > Advanced > Open Expert Configuration** and increase the value of "org.openoffice.Office.Common/Cache/Writer/Writer" from 20 (default) to a value of 600 [1, 2].

To be sure, restart LO writer after saving the above change.

### References

1. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99225#c56
2. https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99225#c19

---

<sup>*</sup>I increased my laptop's RAM from 3GB to 6GB and, in spite of this, the problem persisted. So I am unsure as to how much RAM is "less" RAM. Thankfully the workaround seems to work.